# Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred - Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, azure-web-app-service, publish

I am trying to publish my application to azure via publish profile but getting the below error.

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4283,5):
>   Warning : Retrying the sync because a socket error (10054) occurred.
>   2>Retrying operation 'Serialization' on object sitemanifest
>   (sourcePath). Attempt 1 of 10.

I already have running web applications that I published from my machine. I've deleted and recreated the application in azure, restarted my computer, uninstalled and reinstalled Microsoft Web Deploy 3.6 with no success. I am importing the publish profile provided by azure to my visual studio 2013 to publish the changes. If anyone else has faced this issue, please let me know how can i get out from it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Although I was not able to figure out the issue though but I published it by changing my network connection. I was facing the issue on my home network but when tried from office environment, I could publish my changes. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Must be some kind of firewall interference as it all seemed to work locally. Web Deploy requires port 8172 open.

From your PC add rule in firewall to allow access for port 8172  in inbound and outbound.

Comment: Why would inbound rule be needed for 8172? Azure would connect back to my server???